# Выделение уникальных значений из массива. JS

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть массив `[1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 5, 1]`. Нужно сделать новый массив из уникальных значений из первого массива, т.е. `[4, 9, 2]`.
Что-то делаю не так, не пойму где.

```js
var numbers = [1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 5, 1];
var uniqueNumbers = [];
var swap = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 1; j < numbers.length - 1; j++) {
    if (numbers[i] !== numbers[j]) {
      console.log("swap: " + swap); 
    } else {
      swap = swap + 1;  
    }
  }
  if (swap > 0) {
    swap = 0;
  } else {
    uniqueNumbers.push(numbers[i]);
  }

  console.log('новый массив: ' + uniqueNumbers);
}
```

Comment: прокомментируй каждую строку своего кода

Comment: должен ли сохраняться порядок уникальных чисел?

Comment: Для каждого элемента: если IndexOf != LastIndexOf, то удалять все LastIndexOf, пока они есть...

Comment: `let unique = array.filter((v, i, s) => s.indexOf(v) === s.lastIndexOf(v));`

Answer (score 1):

Хоть лучше варианта чем в комментариях не придумать, есть вот такой вариант с `reduce`:

```js
var numbers = [1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 5, 1];
var counts = numbers.reduce((a, e) => (a[e] ? a[e]++ : a[e]=1) && a, {});
var unique = numbers.filter(el => counts[el] === 1);
console.log(JSON.stringify(unique))
```

Answer (score 0):

Всё решил. Всем спасибо.

```js
var numbers = [1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 5, 1];
var uniqueNumbers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < numbers.length; i++) {
  var swap = 0;
  var str = numbers[i];
  for (var j = 0; j < numbers.length; j++) {
    if (numbers[j] == str) {
      swap++;
    }
  }
  if (swap == 1) {
    uniqueNumbers.push(str);
  }
}
console.log('новый массив: ' + uniqueNumbers);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function get_unique(arr) {
    let new_arr = [];
    for (let element of arr) {
        if (new_arr.includes(element))
            new_arr.splice(new_arr.indexOf(element), 1);
        else
            new_arr.push(element);
    }
    return new_arr;
}


let numbers = [1, 4, 5, 9, 2, 5, 1];
console.log(`New array: ${get_unique(numbers)}`);
```